# Typescript Definitions Modification

Tags: typescript, webpack, ionic2, typescript-typings, type-definition

I have a couple of modifications that I need to make to some typescript definition files.  Up until now I have been making these modifications manually - a bit of a pain if I wipe out my node_modules directory and start afresh, or if I install my code on a new machine.  But the changes are only small and it worked.  However now I want to build my code using a service that calls npm install as part of the build process - of course my modifications are unknown to this process.  I've included one of the modifications that I have to make below:

```
Add the following:
adapter(param1: string, param2: any): Static; 

After the first line in node_modules\@types\pouchdb-core\index.d.ts in the following Interface:
interface Static extends EventEmitter

In order to avoid an error with the following statement in data-service.ts:
PouchDB.adapter('writableStream', replicationStream.adapters.writableStream);
```

My question is how can I make this type of modification outside of my node_modules directory so that the external build process will know about the required modifications.

I am using Ionic 2 which uses Webpack.

Comment: It would be useful to see how you import the modules you want to modify.

Comment: @JamesMonger I use a simple import statement for PouchDB: import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

Comment: For one of my projects I added a "postinstall" step in my package.json which runs a bash script to make the modifications.  The correct way to do this would probably be to fork the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could fix this particular issue by adding the following to my declarations.d.ts file:

```
declare namespace PouchDB {
  interface Static {  adapter: any; }
}
```

Comment: Is your `declarations.d.ts` file in source control?